# ReactJS: Group data by months in the same year

Tags: reactjs

I have data from api that looks like the following

```
[{
commission_total: "4740.00"
country: "Kentop"
created_at: "Jun 30, 2020"
deposit: "0.00"
}

{
commission_total: "4760.00"
country: "Kentop2"
created_at: "Jul 1, 2020"
deposit: "0.00"
}]
```

I am trying to group the data by month of the same year. How do i go about this? I am open to lodash, moment etc. Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

Try with teh following:-

```
let data= [{
    commission_total: "4740.00"
    country: "Kentop"
    created_at: "Jun 30, 2020"
    deposit: "0.00"
    },
    {
    commission_total: "4760.00"
    country: "Kentop2"
    created_at: "Jul 1, 2020"
    deposit: "0.00"
    }]
    
    var grouped = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'created_at'),
                              datalist => datalist.map(item => _.omit(item, 'created_at')));
    
    console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift answer. Is it possible to return specific value lets say ` commission_total` instead of whole object?